# Как настроить директорию для production-сборки в webpack 2?

Tags: webpack2

Хочу настроить другой путь для продакшен-сборки в Webpack-2. У меня такая файловая система:

- `/resources/assets/es6` — исходники
- `/resources/assets/js` — development-сборка
- `/public/js` — production-сборка

На данный момент у меня такие настройки для development-сборки:

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname + '/resources/assets/es6',

    entry: {
        index: './01indexEP.js',
        about: './02aboutEP.js',
        business: './03businessEP.js',
        feedback: './05feedbackEP.js'
    },

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/resources/assets/js/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    }

    // ...

}
```

Как прописать другой путь для production-сборки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочешь сразу 2 конфигурации, то можно [сделать так](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations):

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = [{

    context: __dirname + '/resources/assets/es6',

    entry: {
        index: './01indexEP.js',
        about: './02aboutEP.js',
        business: './03businessEP.js',
        feedback: './05feedbackEP.js'
    },

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/resources/assets/js/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    }

    // ...

}, {

    context: __dirname + '/resources/assets/es6',

    entry: {
        index: './01indexEP.js',
        about: './02aboutEP.js',
        business: './03businessEP.js',
        feedback: './05feedbackEP.js'
    },

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js',
        filename: '[name].js'
    }

    // ...
}];
```

А если хочешь, чтобы зависело от `NODE_ENV`, то лучше так:

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const webpack = require('webpack');

const output_path = NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
    (_dirname + '/public/js'):
    (_dirname + '/resources/assets/js');

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname + '/resources/assets/es6',

    entry: {
        index: './01indexEP.js',
        about: './02aboutEP.js',
        business: './03businessEP.js',
        feedback: './05feedbackEP.js'
    },

    output: {
        path: output_path,
        filename: '[name].js'
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Я правильно Вас понял, что в первом случае две конфигурации выполняются одновременно?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Да.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Ссылка на документацию https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations.